# Where can we discuss issues related to theoretical computer science community?

Tags: soft-question

The cstheory website is a QA site and is not appropriate place for discussion so I want to know if there is a place for discussing issues related to the theoretical computer science community. I know that these issues are sometimes discussed on theory blogs (like the [computational complexity](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/) blog) and also some researchers post their ideas on their own blog or twitter, but is there a more general site/forum to discuss the issues related to theoretical computer science community (e.g. conferences)?

Comment: Enough advertisement of your idea.

Comment: This is not a research level question in TCS.

Comment: I don't think there is a need to state the details of what you want to discuss. I am modifying the question to make it more general.

Comment: I guess the [Academia SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16617/academia?referrer=Y8fSxbIvvuEjazD_NAENyw2) will be appropriate, if and when it is launched.

Comment: This may be the nature of the site, but it is a bit confusing to see the edited question and the downvotes.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto, sorry it was not the point.

Comment: @TysonWilliams, this is a fact indeed.

Comment: @Kaveh, thank you for saying what I was not able to write correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't see the original question, but the new cstheory blog might be a good place, once we have threaded comments

Comment: and some posts... :P

Comment: I suppose you are talking about this one: http://cstheory.blogoverflow.com/? Thanks it's exactly what I was looking for!